# AWS Glue locally: convert pandas df to delta

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, delta-lake

I run my AWS Glue jobs locally in a docker container (AWS Glue lib 4.0) and want to convert/write a pandas dataframe to delta format.

I added

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("YourAppName") \
        .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension") \
        .config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog") \
        .getOrCreate()
    sys.argv += ['--datalake-formats', 'delta']
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['datalake-formats'])
```

but this line

`spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df).write.format('delta').save('myfile.delta')`

give me still the error `Failed to find data source: delta.`

I dont' get what iam missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/big-data/develop-and-test-aws-glue-version-3-0-jobs-locally-using-a-docker-container/) :

"Glue 4.0: Add native data lake libraries
AWS Glue 4.0 Docker image supports native data lake libraries; Apache Hudi, Delta Lake, and Apache Iceberg.
You can pass the environment variable DATALAKE_FORMATS to load the relevant JAR files.

`-e DATALAKE_FORMATS=hudi,delta,iceberg`"

When you set this env variable starting your docker container it will do following

```
Adding delta-2.1.0 libs to Spark Classpath
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Glue expert, but it looks like that you're specifying `--datalake-formats` too late, when job is already started. Per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html), you need to specify that parameter should be specified in the `aws glue start-job-run ...`, not in your code.

Comment: I found the way in the documentation. 
PS: i saw your other answers that helped me and were glad u were posting, keep writing here :)